# MyBatis + Spring with collection resultmap always throws NullPointerException

Tags: spring, mybatis

when im trying to read records that has multiple sub relationship with mybatis..
it will always throws null exception;;;

here is my setting

```
<resultMap id="UserMap" type="user">
    <id column="id" property="id" javaType="string" />
    <result column="pswd" property="pswd" javaType="string" />
    <result column="name" property="name" javaType="string" />
    <result column="useYn" property="useYn" javaType="string" />
    <result column="useLimitedSearchYn" property="useLimitedSearchYn"     javaType="string" />
    <result column="email" property="email" javaType="string" />
    <result column="emailUseYn" property="emailUseYn" javaType="string" />
    <result column="registDatetime" property="registDatetime" javaType="date" />
    <result column="updateDatetime" property="updateDatetime" javaType="date" />
    <collection property="roles" column="{id=id}" notNullColumn="roleCode" javaType="list" ofType="userRole">
        <id column="id" property="id" javaType="string" />
        <id column="roleCode" property="roleCode" javaType="string" />
        <result column="roleUseYn" property="roleUseYn" javaType="string" />
        <result column="roleRegistDatetime" property="roleRegistDatetime" javaType="date" />
    </collection>
</resultMap>
```

and query is

```
<select id="selectOne" resultType="user" resultMap="UserMap">
    SELECT User.id, User.pswd, User.name, User.useYn, User.useLimitedSearchYn, User.email, User.emailUseYn, User.registDatetime, User.updateDatetime,
        UserRole.roleCode, UserRole.roleRegistDatetime
    FROM User 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN UserRole ON User.id = UserRole.id
    WHERE User.id = #{id}
</select>
```

and target table is..

```
create table User
(
   id                   varchar(26) not null,
   pswd                 varchar(40) not null,
   name                 varchar(40) not null,
   useYn                char(1) default 'Y',
   useLimitedSearchYn   char(1) default 'N',
   email                varchar(80),
   emailUseYn           char(1) default 'N',
   registDatetime       datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   updateDatetime       datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   primary key (id)
);

create table UserRole
(
   id                   varchar(26) not null,
   roleCode             varchar(40) not null,
   roleUseYn            char(1) default 'N',
   roleRegistDatetime   datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   primary key (id, roleCode)
);

INSERT INTO User (id, pswd, name, registDatetime, updateDatetime)
VALUES ('super', SHA('admin'), 'Admin', NOW(), NOW());

INSERT INTO UserRole (id, roleCode, roleUseYn, roleRegistDatetime)
VALUES ('super', 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'Y', NOW());

INSERT INTO UserRole (id, roleCode, roleUseYn, roleRegistDatetime)
VALUES ('super', 'ROLE_USER', 'Y', NOW());
```

and Object is ....

```
@Alias("user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String id;
    private String pswd;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String emailUseYn;
    private String useLimitedSearchYn;
    private String useYn;
    private Date registDatetime;
    private Date updateDatetime;
    private List<UserRole> roles;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPswd() {
        return pswd;
    }

    public void setPswd(String pswd) {
        this.pswd = pswd;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmailUseYn() {
        return emailUseYn;
    }

    public void setEmailUseYn(String emailUseYn) {
        this.emailUseYn = emailUseYn;
    }

    public String getUseYn() {
        return useYn;
    }

    public void setUseYn(String useYn) {
        this.useYn = useYn;
    }

    public String getUseLimitedSearchYn() {
        return useLimitedSearchYn;
    }

    public void setUseLimitedSearchYn(String useLimitedSearchYn) {
        this.useLimitedSearchYn = useLimitedSearchYn;
    }

    public Date getRegistDatetime() {
        return registDatetime;
    }

    public void setRegistDatetime(Date registDatetime) {
        this.registDatetime = registDatetime;
    }

    public Date getUpdateDatetime() {
        return updateDatetime;
    }

    public void setUpdateDatetime(Date updateDatetime) {
        this.updateDatetime = updateDatetime;
    }

    public List<UserRole> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<UserRole> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}


@Alias("userRole")
public class UserRole implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String id;
    private String roleCode;
    private String roleUseYn;
    private Date roleRegistDatetime;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRoleCode() {
        return roleCode;
    }

    public void setRoleCode(String roleCode) {
        this.roleCode = roleCode;
    }

    public String getRoleUseYn() {
        return roleUseYn;
    }

    public void setRoleUseYn(String roleUseYn) {
        this.roleUseYn = roleUseYn;
    }

    public Date getRoleRegistDatetime() {
        return roleRegistDatetime;
    }

    public void setRoleRegistDatetime(Date roleRegistDatetime) {
        this.roleRegistDatetime = roleRegistDatetime;
    }
}
```

and using version is...

```
compile "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.39"
compile "org.mybatis:mybatis:3.4.1"
compile "org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:1.3.0"
```

with this setting it will throws exception like this..

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
### The error may exist in /persistence/mysql/mybatis/mapper/UserMapper.xml
### The error may involve persistence.mysql.mybatis.mapper.UserMapper.selectOne
### The error occurred while handling results
### SQL: SELECT User.id, User.pswd, User.name, User.useYn, User.useLimitedSearchYn, User.email, User.emailUseYn, User.registDatetime, User.updateDatetime,    UserRole.roleCode, UserRole.roleRegistDatetime    FROM User     LEFT OUTER JOIN UserRole ON User.id = UserRole.id    WHERE User.id = ?
### Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:79)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:447)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.selectOne(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:167)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:82)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:53)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.selectOne(Unknown Source)
    at sample.dao.UserDao.selectOne(UserDao.java:29)
    at sample.dao.UserDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$48655e9a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    at sample.profiling.ProfilingAspect.profileDao(ProfilingAspect.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at sample.dao.UserDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4dce2a87.selectOne(<generated>)
    at sample.service.UserService.getUser(UserService.java:27)
    at sample.service.UserService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$252104e0.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    at sample.profiling.ProfilingAspect.profileService(ProfilingAspect.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at sample.service.UserService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6a14231c.getUser(<generated>)
    at test.service.TestUserService.testGetUser(TestUserService.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
### The error may exist in /persistence/mysql/mybatis/mapper/UserMapper.xml
### The error may involve persistence.mysql.mybatis.mapper.UserMapper.selectOne
### The error occurred while handling results
### SQL: SELECT User.id, User.pswd, User.name, User.useYn, User.useLimitedSearchYn, User.email, User.emailUseYn, User.registDatetime, User.updateDatetime,    UserRole.roleCode, UserRole.roleRegistDatetime   FROM User     LEFT OUTER JOIN UserRole ON User.id = UserRole.id    WHERE User.id = ?
### Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:150)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:141)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:434)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getPropertyMappingValue(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:455)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.applyPropertyMappings(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:424)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getRowValue(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:860)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValuesForNestedResultMap(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:825)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:311)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:286)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:183)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:64)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.doQuery(ReuseExecutor.java:60)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:324)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:109)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:83)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:148)
    ... 84 more
```

but with

```
compile "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.39"
compile "org.mybatis:mybatis:3.2.8"
compile "org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:1.2.3"
```

it works fine and return result what i want.
is there anything what i missing..?

thanks for reading...

Answer (score 0):

it raised from

```
column="{id=id}"
```

from collection element "column="{property=column}""

but it is necessary for matching subsequential data, i think.

without this how can i match subsequential data and collect those things?